# How to open & access navigation side drawer in appium ? I am using java language for automation in appium

Tags: java, android, appium-android

My code but it is not working:

```
MobileElement el = (MobileElement) driver.findElementById("jpb.com.upisimulator:id/action_bar");
        MobileElement el2 = el.findElementByName("Open navigation drawer");
        el2.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use content description for that.

```
driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("Open navigation drawer").click();
```